# Click on a part to open a gui then sell a developer product by clicking on a TXTButton. [ROBLOX]

Tags: user-interface, lua, roblox

All is in the question. When you click on a Part, the gui open and you got a button. When you click on it, a developer product seller appear and you need to buy it. If you don't, nothing happens. But if you buy it, you get a tool cloned from ServerStorage. (The tool is a iPad)

Here is the developer product ID : 37693110

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [the tutorial](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=The_Fundamentals_of_Scripting_with_GUIs) to gain some understandings of how GUIs works.

To listen on clicks on a part, you use [ClickDetectors](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/ClickDetector).

You can [prompt a purchase](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/MarketplaceService/PromptProductPurchase) of a [developer product](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Developer_product), and then confirm that a Player have bought it with [ProcessReceipt](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/MarketplaceService/ProcessReceipt).

To make the click detection work, put the following script in a part:

```
local Block = script.Parent

local ClickDetector = Instance.new("ClickDetector")
ClickDetector.Parent = Block
ClickDetector.MouseClick:connect(function(Player)
    -- Stuff
end)
```

To show a player the GUI, you can use:

```
local GUI = game.ServerStorage.PurchaseGUI
GUI:Clone().Parent = Player.PlayerGUI
```

Where `game.ServerStorage.PurchaseGUI` is your GUI and `Player` is the [Player](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Player). If a GUI is in the [PlayerGUI](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/PlayerGui), it is drawn. Unless you tell it [not to](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/GuiObject/Visible).

To [listen on a click](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/GuiButton/MouseButton1Click) on a [TextButton](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/TextButton), you can use:

```
local Button = <Button Here>
Button.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
    -- Stuff here
end)
```

To prompt a purchase, you can use the following code:

```
local ProductId = 37693110
Game:GetService("MarketplaceService"):PromptProductPurchase(Player, ProductId)
```

Where `Player` is a player and `ProductId` is your product id (37693110 is your product's id)

To listen on the purchase, you can [use](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/MarketplaceService/ProcessReceipt#Example):

```
local MarketplaceService = game:GetService("MarketplaceService")
local ProductId = 37693110

function MarketplaceService.ProcessReceipt(ReceiptInfo)
    local Player = game:GetService("Players"):GetPlayerByUserId(ReceiptInfo.PlayerId)
    if not player then
        return Enum.ProductPurchaseDecision.NotProcessedYet
    end

    if receiptInfo.ProductId == ProductId then
        -- Do stuff
        return Enum.ProductPurchaseDecision.PurchaseGranted
    else
        return Enum.ProductPurchaseDecision.NotProcessedYet
    end
end
```

And to [clone](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/Instance/Clone) a tool:

```
game.ServerStorage.iPad:Clone().Parent = Player.Backpack
```

As a tool is granted to a player by placing it in the [Backpack](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/Backpack). You might want to consider also adding it to the [StarterPack](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/StarterPack) if you want it to persist respawns.

You might also want to [save the information](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Data_store) about the purchase so that the player gets the tool when rejoining the game.

And if you put it together:

A server [script](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/Script) in [ServerScriptService](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/ServerScriptService):

```
local ProductId = 37693110
local MarketplaceService = game:GetService("MarketplaceService")
local Block = script.Parent
local GUI = game.ServerStorage.PurchaseGUI

local ClickDetector = Instance.new("ClickDetector")
ClickDetector.Parent = Block
ClickDetector.MouseClick:connect(function(Player)
    GUI:Clone().Parent = Player.PlayerGUI
end)

function MarketplaceService.ProcessReceipt(ReceiptInfo)
    local Player = game:GetService("Players"):GetPlayerByUserId(ReceiptInfo.PlayerId)
    if not player then
        return Enum.ProductPurchaseDecision.NotProcessedYet
    end

    if receiptInfo.ProductId == ProductId then
        game.ServerStorage.iPad:Clone().Parent = Player.Backpack
        return Enum.ProductPurchaseDecision.PurchaseGranted
    else
        return Enum.ProductPurchaseDecision.NotProcessedYet
    end
end
```

And a [local script](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/LocalScript) in the button in the GUI:

```
local ProductId = 37693110
local Button = script.Parent
local Player = game.Players.LocalPlayer

Button.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
    Game:GetService("MarketplaceService"):PromptProductPurchase(Player, ProductId)
end)
```